# file size limitation of flex file uploader

Tags: php, flash, apache-flex, cakephp, file-upload

Does anyone know the file size limitation of flex file uploader?

Currently I'm working on a project that uses flex and cake php. I heard that there is a 1GB of file size limitation in flex file uploader. If this is true w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there isn't a file size limitation of Flex in regards to file uploading - I can't find any reference to such a limit anywhere, nor does it seem very likely. You're more likely to run into some limit of the place you're uploading the file to (a FTP server, etc.)